# Javassist: Source Code and Empty Lines

Tags: java, decompiling, instrumentation, javassist

Good time!

I've just started using Javassist and there are several points I don't understand for now.

1. First of all, when I use the `ctMethod.insertAt()` method, I need to specify a line number from my source code to insert a code. An intrumentation is taking place in a class loading phase, so am I right that javassist contains a decompiler to transform compiled classes into a source code?
2. I've prepared some tests to verify my transformers' work. The majority of them use the following algorithm to substitute block of code with the specified ones:

   ```
   CodeAttribute codeAttribute = ctMethod.getMethodInfo().getCodeAttribute();
   LineNumberAttribute lineNumberAttribute = (LineNumberAttribute) codeAttribute.getAttribute(LineNumberAttribute.tag);

   int startPC = lineNumberAttribute.toStartPc(startLine);
   int endPC = lineNumberAttribute.toStartPc(endLine);

   byte[] code = codeAttribute.getCode();
   for (int i = startPC; i < endPC; i++) {
       code[i] = CodeAttribute.NOP;
   }

   ...

   ctMethod.insertAt(startLine, wrappedCode.toString());
   ```

   There is the method I try to instrument:[image]
   **Please note, that there are several empty lines: 12, 16 and 19.**

I try to

- comment the first block,
- instead of the second block put the 'Instead of the second block!!!' line (comment the second block and insert the substituting line before it),
- comment the first single line,
- instead of the second single line put the 'Instead of the second line!!!' line (comment the second line and insert the substituting line before it).

When I specify the line numbers as they go in the source code, it does not work at all - here is the resulting output:

```
Test block 1 line 1
Test block 1 line 2
Test block 1 line 3
Instead of the second block!!!
Test block 2 line 1
Test block 2 line 2
Test block 2 line 3
Test single line 1
Test single line 2
Instead of the second line!!!
```

but when I set the line numbers as if there is no empty lines, everything works as expected.
I've tried to decompile the *Sleeping* class with the JD decompiler and it showed the following: [image]
**There is also a notion of empty lines.**

So am I right that the internal javassist's decompiler eliminates empty lines and when I specify line numbers I need to evaluate a line index removing empty lines?

Comment: Was about to ask this too, for me it seems like sometimes it will count the blank lines, sometimes not. It makes it extremely hard to work with classes that I dont have the source for, I have no idea at which line I have to insert my code because java assists decompiler decompiles differently than mine.